# How do I prevent reloadRowsAtIndexPaths to block the user input?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, scroll

I have implemented a client for a paginated REST service where I populate the whole table with empty entries and then load them in the background using pagination when the user starts scrolling the table.

This seems to work very well except for a little detail: I am calling `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:` in the main UI thread (because `UIKit` requires so), and I *feel* the animation sometimes makes me lose input touches.

This is, the user starts scrolling through the list and items start to load. Sometimes a reload animation happens at the same time the user is just touching the screen again, and this touch is not recognized. The scrolling then doesn't continue and stops. It doesn't happen all the time, and I guess it is an infrequent user case (the user is expected to read each row of results before scrolling down) but it annoys me to no end.

I'm doing most of my animations with blocks and the flag `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction` is really helpful, so is there a block version of `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` where the reload animation would not block the user interaction with the scrolling?

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to reload the items?  Are you doing your REST calls in a separate thread?  How are you indicating to the user that loading is starting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the solution you seek is to background-load your data in a thread (as you describe) and only call `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:` once the data is received and ready to display.  You should also probably redisplay the data NOT animated.

I don't think there's anything you can do to get around the missed touches with your current scheme.  My suggestion is to "do what iOS wants" rather than "try to cajole iOS to do what you want."  Yes, probably not the answer you wanted to hear, but I think that's just the way it works.

(Btw, you can always use [bugreporter.apple.com](http://bugreporter.apple.com) to make an enhancement request! :)

Comment: So far using the bug reporter has been worse than talking to walls, but reading your post reminded me of something I'll try now...

Comment: Nah, not working. Let's use bugreporter and hope for the best.